# jQuery, add days to date

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Ruby on Rails application I have a field in which user can set date. This field value has the following format:

```
$('#search_form_handover_date').val()
#returns
"15-07-2014 09:00"
```

Now How can I for example add to this date 3 days, to have:
"18-07-2014 09:00"

Comment: Looks like an invalid date format, are you using a datepicker, and why is the date in that format ?

Comment: I'm using this:
http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
And my format in javascipt file is:
format:'d-m-Y H:i'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), if you don't mind using a 3rd party JS lib, you can just do.....

```
// As the format you gave is non standard, you need to tell moment what it's getting
var myTime = moment("15-07-2014 09:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");

console.log(myTime.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));

var newTime = moment(myTime).add('3', 'days');

console.log(newTime.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
```

Comment: Thank's for help but I don't want to use external libaries. I'm very close to the solution. I only need convert:
Date {Fri Jul 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)} to this:
"18-07-2014 09:00"

Comment: I decided to use moment.js because it is a great libary. Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below, if your date string preserve the same format always,

```
var date = "15-07-2014 09:00";
var dateParts = (date.split(" ")[0]).split("-");
var timeParts = (date.split(" ")[1]).split(":");
var dateObj = new Date(dateParts[2],dateParts[1]-1,dateParts[0],timeParts[0],timeParts[1]);
dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate()+3);
console.log(dateObj)

//If you don't use any library like Jquery datepicker, you have to use basic js operation to format the date (but not recommend)   

console.log(formateDate(dateObj))

function formateDate(DateObj)
{
return addLeadingZeros(dateObj.getDate())+"-"+addLeadingZeros(dateObj.getMonth()+1)+"-"+dateObj.getFullYear()+" "+addLeadingZeros(dateObj.getHours())+":"+addLeadingZeros(dateObj.getMinutes());

}

function addLeadingZeros(intArg)
{
    return ('0' + intArg).slice(-2)
}
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. But the last thing I want to have this dateObj as a string in this format: "15-07-2014 09:00". Did you know how to do it?

Comment: I edited the answer, but I suggest you to use some library to format your date.